# provisional certification issue in device?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I am clicking my app on a device, it throws messages like "your provision cerificate expired".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are wondering why your question is being voted on to close, you should know that a simple google search would help you out.  There are lots of resources out there with good tutorials on certificates and provisioning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to renew your certificate and then update the provisioning profile to use that new cert.

Start with Keychain access to create the CSR's and then go here:
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action